# Адресат вызова создал исключение в WPF

Tags: c#, исключения

Есть основной класс и дополнительный, в дополнительный я передаю ссылку на основной, где после расчета добавляю созданный объект в таблицу. Первый раз добавляется без ошибок, на след итерации выскакивает исключение. Как это можно убрать? Именно с помощью метода `dataGrid.Items.Add()`. Wnd содержит ссылку на основной класс. Возникает исключение на строчке создания нового объекта zet в цикле на 2 итерации

```
            ResultData zet;
            for (int i = 0; i < paramOptFirst.Count; i++)
            {
                    zet = new ResultData(Timeframe, startDateOpt + " -- " + endDateOpt, startDateFrwd + " -- " + endDateFrwd, resultOptOne[i][0], resultOptOne[i][1], resultOptOne[i][2], resultOptOne[i][3], resultOptOneF[i][0], resultOptOneF[i][1], resultOptOneF[i][2], resultOptOneF[i][3], paramOptFirst);
                    wnd.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
                    {
                        wnd.dataGrid.Items.Add(zet);
                    }));
            }
```

Исключение - `An unhandled exception of type System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 
Additional information: Адресат вызова создал исключение.`

Comment: Какое именно исключение?

Comment: @tym32167 я указал в названии темы, но добавил еще в описании.

Comment: Как изначально попадают элементы в dataGrid?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик элементы попадают только здесь, нигде больше. Чтобы все расчеты не выносить в основной класс, создал второй, где делаю всё и заношу в основную форму через BeginInvoke

Comment: Покажите текст исключения, если есть тексты вложенных исключений и стектрейс. То, что вы указали - этого не достаточно.

Comment: @tym32167 В итоге найдено решение проблемы : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985217/mscorlib-pdb-not-loaded-yet-the-mscorlib-dll-is-not-missing 
А про какие тексты исключения вы говорите? Где они именно находятся?

Comment: Исключение состоит из нескольких полей, например сообщение исключения, стек трейс, вложенные исключения. Вы показали только тип и сообщение. Стек вызовов и все, что вложено, вы не показали. [Как пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xadLm.png)